# After downloading, do I have to install it? If so, how?

Tags: 12.04, installation

My wife had Ubuntu 10.10 on her lap top and I have downloaded 12.04.2 to the desktop.

Do I have to do anything else or does it automatically install itself ?

Comment: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/65926) <-- Does it help? I recommend you perform a full backup before trying anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"I have downloaded 12.04.2"_? Did you download and save an ISO file to your desktop? Or did you use something like _Update Manager_ to "download" the new version?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.10 ([screenshot](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Ubuntu_10.10_preview.png)) *looks very different* from Ubuntu 12.04 ([screenshot](http://www.blogti.microcampsp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ubuntu-12_04.png)). Restart the computer, and if everything still looks the same after "downloading" 12.04, that means you still need to install it.

If you follow the link recommended by Eric in the comments, it should help you install 12.04 properly.

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/65926)